# Safe way to filters including account id or user id in SQL query

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I would like to allows our users to filers the data by our API. We want to apply `accountId` along with all filters(provided by the user) in the where condition.  I don't our users to manipulate the account ID. What is the safe to apply filters along with account Id?

We want to avoid any `sql injection` and getting results for all `accountIds`.
We are thinking of writing subquery. We really doubt about the performances.

**Normal Query:**

```
select any(accountId), appName, avg(duration) from performance_table where
accountId = '500' and  eventDateTime >= now() - 30 * 60 and env = "production"
group by appName order by appName limit 10
```

**Using Sub Query:**

*Sub Query 1:*

```
select any(accountId), appName, avg(duration) from (select * from  
performance_table where
accountId = '500' and  eventDateTime >= now() - 30 * 60) where env = "production"
group by appName order by appName limit 10
```

*Sub Query 2:*

```
select * from (select any(accountId), appName, avg(duration) from performance_table 
where accountId = '500' and eventDateTime >= now() - 30 * 60
where env = "production" group by appName order by appName limit 10) where accountId = '500'
```

Could you please suggest the safe way of doing it?

Comment: How will subquery help here?

Comment: Which language/framework do you use to implement your API?

Comment: Node.js and Go. As of now, we are doing it in Node.js.

Comment: @sskoko I am thinking subquery will be filtered by parent query. I am not sure.

Comment: `select accountId, appName, avg(duration)...group by appName`  looks like a wrong query to me.. Misusing MySQL `GROUP BY` "feature"

Comment: MySQL and postgresql are two different products with different syntax. Removed the conflicting product tags. Pls add the one back that you use - if that is relevant to your question at all.

Comment: @RaymondNijland You are correct. I have correct with `any` function. You also correct. We can add the accountId in the `group by`

Comment: @Shadow Sorry about it. I have added clickhouse.

Comment: @IvanBlinkov Do you have any findings?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can achieve that by prepending `accountId = '500'` to the where clause and generate something like

```
....   where accountId = '500'  and ( <user predicates> )
```